# How to get full page background color for login page by using ng-class in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I am struggling to set the full page background color for login page. While I am giving background for login page, it is getting through the all views in my app.

Here is my code.

Html:

```
<div id="myDiv" ng-class="{'login-bg': showBgColor}">
```

Css:

```
body.myClass.login-bg {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

Js:

```
var loginController= function($rootScope, $state, myService) {

    var vm = this;
vm.showBgColor = true;

        });

    };

};
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't assign your value to scope, that's why you can't get.

try this below code

```
var loginController= function($rootScope, $state, myService,$scope) {

    var vm = this.$scope;
vm.showBgColor = true;    
        });    
    };    
};
```